# Intellij Idea EJB library for remote client

Tags: interface, intellij-idea, ejb

How can i create jar with remote interface (of Session Bean for example) for remote client. I tried experiment with artifacts, but in artifacts
- i can create jar and include whole output directory with class of bean and interface.
- or include file of interface that will be in root of jar without packages directories
What i want to do is simple in Netbeans in this tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html in "Creating the Java Class Library" chapter.
Please help me create jar for remote clients in Idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'Create Directory' button in 'Output Layout' tree in the artifact editor to create desired packages in the jar and then drag'n'drop class-files into that package. However it would be better to extract classes which need to be packed to a jar into a separate module and add this module to the artifact as a whole. This way you can ensure that these classes doesn't have dependencies which aren't included in the jar and also instruct IDEA to compile these classes whenever the artifact is built. Note that extracting a module doesn't necessary mean that you need to physically move these classes into a separate directory. If all these classes are located under a single package you can create a module with a source root pointing to the corresponding package and specify 'package prefix' for this source root accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I will try ur method. And I cant understand why such great and powerful IDE like IDEA dont have simple tool for that like in NetBeans.

Comment: The NetBeans tutorial suggests to create a separate project for the remote interface. You can easy do a similar thing in IDEA: create a new module (which is an analogue of a project in NetBeans) and select 'Ejb' on the last page in the New Module Wizard. IDEA will automatically create a jar artifact which includes the output of the module.